# A c++ program memory leak problem when deserializing

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

This is my code:

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

class A
{
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access; // After checking by valgrind, "definitively lost" appears here

    public:

        uint64_t num;

        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & num;
        }
};

void serialization(A* t, const string path)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(path, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa<<*t;
    ofs.close();
}

void deserialization(A* t, const string path)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(path, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia>>*t;
    ifs.close();
}

int main()
{
    // serialization
    A* a = new A();
    (*a).num = 1;
    serialization(a, "/../..");


    // deserialization
    A* a = new A();  // After checking by valgrind, "definitively lost" appears here
    deserialization(a, "/../..");
    cout << (*a).num << endl;
    delete(a);

    return 0;

}
```

In the real project, I need to deserialize an object to a pointer and return the pointer to other functions. Unfortunately, this code was detected by Valgrind and there were two memory leaks, that is, two places where I added comments. The above code is only a description of bugs. How should I fix these two bugs? How should I deserialize an object to the heap memory space pointed by a pointer.

Should I not first create an empty object to initialize the pointer, and then assign the deserialized object to it? Whether this creates two objects, one is the initialization object and the other is the deserialized object. The initialization object is leaked.

Comment: You use `new` but there is no `delete`. Either use *smart pointers* or delete the objects when you're done with them.

Comment: If you're using dumb pointers instead of smart pointers in C++, you should really consider why you would do that. Also, there is zero reason to pass by dumb pointer. You could pass by reference or smart pointer.

Comment: fwiw, (raw) pointers and dynamic allocation are related, but you can have one without the other. Assuming they always come together will get you stuck in the wrong concepts. Consider smart pointers and container and see raw pointers as what they are, they point somewhere not more

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of A but not deleting the value you originally created.

If you want to use raw pointers (not recommended as the comments above say) you simply need to delete the hanging pointer.

```cpp
int main()
{
    // serialization
    A* a = new A();
    (*a).num = 1;
    serialization(a, "/../..");

    delete(a); // <--------- Memory leak

    // deserialization
    A* a = new A();  // After checking by valgrind, "definitively lost" appears here
    deserialization(a, "/../..");
    cout << (*a).num << endl;
    delete(a);

    return 0;

}
```

Alternatively and even better use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) and [arrow operators](https://www.scaler.com/topics/arrow-operator-in-cpp/) :

```
int main()
{
    // serialization
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
    a->num = 1; // <----- Arrow operator is a better and safer accessor for pointers
    serialization(a, "/../..");

    // deserialization
    a = std::make_unique<A>();  // <--- No need to create new *a* just replace it 
    deserialization(a, "/../..");
    cout << a->num << endl;

    return 0;

}
```